# Mahout - How to unset Mahout_local to run in Hadoop filesystem?

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration, mahout

Previously I set Mahout_Local=TRUE to let the program run locally. I am using OSX 10.9 and in ~./bash_profile:

```
export MAHOUT_LOCAL="TRUE"
```

Now I want the program to run in Hadoop filesystem. How do I unset MAHOUT_LOCAL to do so?

I tried:

```
export MAHOUT_LOCAL=""
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then run the job. But still I got:

```
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath.
MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, running locally
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
unset MAHOUT_LOCAL
```

What version of mahout are you using? The Mahout 0.8 (available [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Downloads)) distribution does the variable check on line 122 of ./bin/mahout:

```
if [ "$MAHOUT_LOCAL" != "" ]; then
    echo "MAHOUT_LOCAL is set, so we don't add HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath."
elif [ -n "$HADOOP_CONF_DIR"  ] ; then
  echo "MAHOUT_LOCAL is not set; adding HADOOP_CONF_DIR to classpath."
  CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR
fi
```

So setting the variable to the empty string should work.

What does

```
echo $MAHOUT_LOCAL
```

give you?